# Run additional asertion code after Botium Bindings completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

How can I run additional assertion after Botium Binding is completed?

```
const bb = new BotiumBindings({ convodirs: ['/spec'] })
BotiumBindings.helper.mocha().setupMochaTestSuite({ bb })

// TODO: GET request to an external API.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to add your custom asserter logic to Botium is by adding your own asserter module to Botium. You can find the details [here](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24477705/Developing+Custom+Asserters), but in short:

1. Create a file *MyCustomAsserter.js*:

```
module.exports = class CustomAsserter {
  constructor (context, caps, globalArgs) {
    this.context = context
    this.caps = caps
    this.globalArgs = globalArgs
  }
  assertConvoStep ({convo, convoStep, args, isGlobal, botMsg}) {
    if (botMsg.message !== 'hugo') throw new Error('expected hugo')
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

2. Register it in *botium.json*

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      ...
      "ASSERTERS": [
        {
          "ref": "MY-ASSERTER-NAME",
          "src": "./MyCustomAsserter.js",
          "global": false,
          "args": {
            "my-arg-1": "something"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

3. Use this asserter in your convo files:

```
my-test-case

#me
hi

#bot
hi
MY-ASSERTER-NAME some-arg1|some-arg2
```